# Unable to access java web application with windows server static ip

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, windows-server-2008

I was unable to access java web application with static ip(public ip) of Windows Server it was getting that **site cant be reached**,
but it was working with **local IP**.

This is the first time i am deploying my java web application in windows server, I exported the **WAR** from eclipse and deployed in Apache tomcat server of Windows Server.

Please help me how to deploy in live windows server. and what is the process to deploy in live windows server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this question, the issue is that, the port i have given in tomcat, the same port is running on some other application, so i have change the port then it works fine.